# Strategy for Arachyr's set dungeon

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-witch-doctor

I want to Master the [Arachyr's set dungeon](http://www.diablofans.com/builds/70418-set-dungeons-witch-doctor-arachyr-set) but I'm having trouble getting the following objective:

> Kill every elite while it is webbed by Spider Queen and being bitten by Piranhas, 5 Elites

I have tried this repeatedly and usually fail on the first or second encouter with an elite, because they die in my Pirhanado without being webbed. I either do too much damage (and the elite dies before its webbed), or I don't do enough (and the Pirhanado runs out before the elite dies).

I know that I can cast Corpse Spiders to direct the Spider Queen to a location, but I dont know what triggers her webbing, or how often it happens.

**Is there an ideal damage level, or strategy, to help complete this objective? Or do I just have to get lucky on all 5 elites?**

Comment: As far as I know Set Dungeon difficulty is not affected by game difficulty or they changed this on the ptr?

Comment: You tried to find a solution/example on YouTube? That's the usual way I solve these kind of problems.

Comment: @Philipp i didnt realize that, im just trying for the seasonal challenge otherwise I'd avoid these set dungeons. I've edited accordingly.

Comment: @MarcBrinkmann there's a YouTube video in the article/post i linked to, and [this one](https://youtu.be/XrQR47tYU-Q) is even more in depth, but still the tip is "just cast your tornado, hit the elite with corpse spiders, and kill the enemy". I feel like im missing something, but it just seems like luck if i can't trigger the webbing.

Comment: Do you use Convention of Elements? This could explain why sometimes you just obliterate the elite. Try to gear in a way that you reduce as much randomness as possible.

Comment: @Philipp i dont use CoE, but i get what you mean. I switch out my wormwood to take locusts out of the equation, and i am literally just using tornado, spiders, and toad to do all dmg. I can post full build later if that helps.

Comment: Don't use Pirhanado - it has reduced duration (4 seconds) and increased cooldown (16).  Use Zombie Piranhas - that's 8 seconds duration and 8 seconds cooldown, and they leap at nearby enemies if you miss your cast slightly.

Comment: @DanSmolinske good point, but pirhanado keeps them in the pirhanas, while other runes let them escape the effect. I'll give zombies a shot but the little success ive had so far has been with pirhanado.

Comment: @Dpeif "affected by Piranhas" does not equal "standing in the pool", especially with Zombie ones. You should see literal piranhas gnawing at the monster.

Comment: @OrcJMR yep, but how do i make aure that theyre webbed and pirhanaed? Seems like the easiest solution is to lock them in one spot with pirhanado and lead my queen there with corpse spiders. With zombie pirhanas, im chasing the elite through minions trying to get my queen to attack it.

Comment: FTR the same thing happens with zombie pirhanas, i just tried.

Comment: Will test more when i can but I'm wondering now if something like attack speed could proc the webbing faster? Or if maybe Bane of the Trapped could help ensure mid-web deaths?

Comment: One more thing to consider: It's beta so it might be that it is just really difficult to complete this set dungeon in the current iteration of the game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After probably 25 tries, I finally beat this set dungeon. I ended up using the [Pirhanado](https://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/witch-doctor/active/piranhas) and [Corpse Spiders](https://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/witch-doctor/active/corpse-spiders) to trap the elite, and rolled a few items for extra damage to beef up my [Firebats](https://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/witch-doctor/active/firebats) (which I thought was overkill, but ended up being crucial). I also included my [Wormwood](https://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/wormwood), [Haunt](https://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/witch-doctor/active/haunt), and a [Ring of Emptiness](https://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/ring-of-emptiness).

I personally had no trouble with the Toad of Hugeness challenge, I just used Corpse Spiders to lure my Queen away from minions (so she didnt kill them) while my Toad sat there and licked them like crazy. It's worth noting that if an off-screen elite is hit by a Toad lick, it will apply a DoT, and with a high damage build this can cause an accidental dungeon failure.

Whenever an elite came on screen, I did my best to clear the area and isolate him, and stay a good distance away, to keep the locusts from Wormwood off of him.

Then I hit him with Pirhanado and Corpse Spiders (to lure the queen to him).

Usually within the first two hits from the queen, the elite becomes webbed, and I would rush him, hit him with Haunt, and slam him with the Firebats.

Basically my plan was to one-shot them all as soon as they appeared webbed, and it only worked with insta-kill level damage (1.2M sheet dmg with multiple Firebats items, listed below), no minions around the elite (to make sure the Queen webs directly on the elite), and making sure they had a decent amount of health to begin with, so they could endure the tornado and queen long enough to be webbed.

This still involved a good deal of luck (I failed once because an errant Haunt killed an elite off screen), and timing (the visual cue for being webbed is subtle and I missed it a few times) but it got me through.

I don't think all of the following Firebats items are necessary, but they helped me hit hard *just with Firebats*, which ended up being the key to one-shotting elites *only when I wanted to*.

Here are the relevant items from my build, and while not all of them are necessary, these are the ones I thought worth mentioning. Depending on your dmg / toughness ratio, you might want to use Mantle of Channeling, or you might not need it at all.

- [Staff of Chiroptera](https://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/staff-of-chiroptera) (cubed)
- [Coils of the First Spider](https://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/coils-of-the-first-spider) (cubed, and just for toughness, didn't really need them here)
- [Ring of Emptiness](https://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/ring-of-emptiness)
- [Mantle of Channeling](https://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/mantle-of-channeling)
- [Bakuli Jungle Wraps](https://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/bakuli-jungle-wraps)
- [Wormwood](https://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/wormwood) to trigger the RoE and Bakuli
- [Haunt](https://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/witch-doctor/active/haunt) to trigger RoE
- [Pirhanado](https://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/witch-doctor/active/piranhas) for CC and to trigger Bakuli